# Why data on service isn't saved when changing routes?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm new to angular and i try to build a small app.
I have this service who holds a variable and a function:

#### data.service.ts

```js
data = [];
getData() {
  this.http.get(url).subscribe((res)=>
  this.data.push(res));
};
```

I also have two routes:

#### app.module.ts (the service is defined here)

```js
import { DataService } from './data.service';
// ...
const appRoutes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }
]
    
@NgModule({
  // ..
  providers: [DataService],
  // ..
})
```

When i use the getData function in the homeComponent it works fine, and the response is added to the data array.
But- and here is the problem- once I navigate to the second route, the data in the service is back to be an empty array.

I would have think that the service is not being "restarted" when i navigate.

So, what is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in StackBlitz.com. There might be an issue with multiple injections of this service instance.

Comment: Post the code where you provide the service.

Comment: Hi Dannom, define the DataService in the providers section in the app.module.ts instead of in each component. As BlizZard says down below, just import it and define it in the component's constructor.

Comment: It is defined in the app.module.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem Found and solved, from a different direction.

I used `<a href="/">` as the link to the routes, which probably causes the application to restart itself every time its clicked. `<a routerlink="/">` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when you move to a different route, all the local data would be deleted and will be initialized with default values. So , if you want to sustain the `data` for use in some other page, you will have to save the values inside a globally declared variable.

For declaring global variables, that can be used in all the pages, firstly create a global.service.ts file and import the file into all the components. Wherever you need you can access these global variables as `this.global.variableName`.

Follow this [link](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) on how to create global services.

Change your codes like

after creating global service, import this global service in your app.module.ts, then in home.component.ts import it like

```
import { GlobalService } from '../global.service';
.
.
.constructor(public global: GlobalService) { }
.
.
getData(){
    this.http.get(url).subscribe((res)=>
    this.global.globalData.push(res);
};
```

Comment: I think that `getData` is actually *in* the global service in OPs code

Comment: yup, but in global.service we should not declare function calls right. We should define all http calls inside another server.service or something, just to keep the code clean

Comment: Hey, thank you but the service is actually already global in my code, provided in the app.module.ts as you mentioned. yet it still doesn't work.